# Event based communication between Hybris cluster nodes

Tags: events, cluster-computing, sap-commerce-cloud

In what use-case would there be a need to communicate between cluster nodes? The ClusterAwareEvent interface offers the possibility to specify a source node and a target node, but shouldn't cluster nodes be as independent of each other as possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there are a few reasons why they would need to communicate or rather why you would want them to communicate.

Firstly there is a concept called the Cache Invalidation Concept, which is where each cluster member holds only valid data, but can communicate with one another by TCP or UDP to mark some cache entries as invalid. For example if a database item has been changed.

A basic overview of the invalidation process:

- Product description is changed. Therefore, all cache entries
  referring to the product are invalid.
- This modification to the description is done on a node, which now has to send a notification to all cluster nodes that the data is invalid.
- Nodes that hold the product in their cache discard the cached data of
  the product and re-retrieve the product from the database the    next
  time the product is used.

Other features of clustering within Hybris where you would want to communicate with other nodes would be:

- Load Balancing
- Semi-Session Failover - This allows sessions(sticky sessions) to transfer to a different cluster. Useful if say a server is going down for maintenance or a hardware defect.

These would be the main reasons I can think of off the top of my head for why you would want clusters to communicate.

Comment: Thank you for the response :)

Comment: No problem, let me know if you want anything else, can do my best to help.

Comment: @Grinch91 can you share an example of a custom event + listener you may have implemented that used ClusterAwareEvent? Your answer seems to include OOTB implementations that Hybris would already have in place, so would help if you can share a custom project implementation scenario as well